# Find a string by index in docx document with docx module

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I am looking through a docx document using docx module and regex.

I have found the text immediately before the string I actually want to extract. How can I reference next string? Can I use the Index at all?

```
for table in wordDoc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            #grabbing the Payment Total Amount
            if 'Total Payment Amount:' in cell.text:
                 print(cell.text)
                 print(cell.text.index)
```

Output:

```
Total Payment Amount:
<built-in method index of str object at 0x000001F9376D26C0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should give you the idea:

```
>>> text = "The quick brown fox"
>>> key = "quick"
>>> start = text.index(key)
>>> start
4
>>> text[start:]
'quick brown fox'
>>> text[start+len(key):]
' brown fox'
```

A few of the finer points:

- `.index()` is a method, not a property, so you need to give it the key value you're after.
- `.index() give you the *starting* offset of the key within the string, you need to add the length of the key to locate the suffix.
- "Slicing" a string to get a suffix is accomplished with an open-ended range (e.g. `s[n:]`). Search on `python string slice` to find more on how that works.
- You may need to account for spaces between words. Using the `.lstrip()` method is probably best for that since it works for no spaces, one space, or multiple spaces.

  ```
  >>> text[start+len(key):].lstrip()
  'brown fox'
  ```